# Stackpanel to Image methods?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

Is there a way to take my existing stackpanel on a WPF page and send it to my printer que as an image? I have some existing print que code so that's not really the core of my question - I'm really just looking to convert the stackpanel to an image in a way that I can send it to the print que.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) class.